# Android User Profile Questions

Tags: android, android-user-profile

I'm looking for technical input on Android User Profiles (both full & restricted).  More specifically I would like to understand:

- Whether it is possible to create an app which runs across all profiles, i.e. is not stopped, paused, restarted when switching user profile.  My focus is NOT limited to activities, but I'm also interested in knowing whether a system-app/service could be created that does this and if so how.
- What life-cycle is maintained for services of the non-active users.  I get the impression that (at least some) services of APKs of a user get started the moment it gets activated in the lock screen (even without unlocking) and then are allowed to keep on running.  But what will happen in low-memory conditions?  Will a service of a non-active user also receive broadcast intents?  Can such a service interact with the user and if so how?

In general: can someone point me to any technical information on the Android profiles features?  There's a lot of articles on how it "looks" to the user, but I could find very little (apart from info on the pm and am command-line tools' options) on how it really works technically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find such documentation?  Im having similar problems.  In particular Im wondering whether an owner User can listen to intents or broadcasts from the other user?

Answer (score 2):

> Whether it is possible to create an app which runs across all profiles, i.e. is not stopped, paused, restarted when switching user profile. My focus is NOT limited to activities, but I'm also interested in knowing whether a system-app/service could be created that does this and if so how.

### Default Android behaviors

By default, an Android application **runs in a specific Android user workspace**, it **does not run for all Android users**.

It means that when the user starts an application, it is started for the current Android user only.
When the application is launched from another Android user, **Android will recreate a new instance of your application**. As Android users can run in the background it means that you can have several instances of the same aplication running in parallel.

**All the Android components of you application** (ie. Services, Activities, BroadcastReceivers and ContentProviders) **will be re-instantiated**.
Most of the time it's the wanted behavior, but it can be a problem for some applications that do system-level handlings that have to be done once for the whole system, without
taking into account Android users (ex: a JobService doing some handling on Bluetooth events).

### Define a singleton component/application

For each component of your app which is not an Activity, you have the possibility to specify that you want it to **run as a singleton** (ie. only one instance will be created for all Android users.).
To do so, the property `android:singleUser=”true”` must be added to the attributes of the component in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the application.

```xml
<!-- Declare a singleUser service in the AndroidManifest.xml -->
<service
    android:name=".MySingleUserService"
    android:singleUser="true" />
```

Any `singleUser` component will always run under the system Android user (ie. the user 0) which can't be stopped by Android, even if you're application is currently running for another Android user.

To be able to use the property `android:singleUser=”true”`:

- your app has to be a system application (either in `system/app/` or `system/priv-app/`).
- you app has to be signed by the platform certificate (by specifying `LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform` in its `Android.mk`).
- your app must declare the use of the following permission in its AndroidManifest.xml.

```html
<!-- Permission needed to use android:singleUser. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
```

### Additional remarks

- If your app only contains `singleUser` components, the entire app will become `singleUser` (ie. only one instance of your app will run for the entire system).
- `android:singleUser=”true”` forces `android:exported=”false”` for your component (except if your app is privleged).
- If a component of your application wants to communicate with a `singleUser` component of the same app via Intents, the default Android APIs can't be used because **Intents do not cross Android users**.
  In that case, you have to use the multi-user Intent exchanges dedicated APIs which are suffixed by *AsUser* (ex: `sendBroadcastAsUser()`, `startServiceAsUser()`, etc.) and which allow to specify the destination Android user (`UserHandle.SYSTEM` in that case). Note that one of the following permissions must be used:

```html
<!-- Permission needed to send intents to components of the SAME app running in another Android user. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
<!-- Permission needed to send intents to components of ANOTHER app running in another Android user. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

> What life-cycle is maintained for services of the non-active users. I get the impression that (at least some) services of APKs of a user get started the moment it gets activated in the lock screen (even without unlocking) and then are allowed to keep on running. But what will happen in low-memory conditions? Will a service of a non-active user also receive broadcast intents? Can such a service interact with the user and if so how?

As I've mentionned above, an Android user can continue to run in the background even if they are not the active one (at least until Android 10). If resources are low, Android can stop any Android user which is not the system user (ie. stop all their running applications). So a Service can continue to run on an Android user which is currently running in the background until the user is stopped.

As I've also mentioned above, Intents do not cross Android users. So if you have a BroadcastReceiver registered in the user 10 and that an Intent is sent from the user 11, it won't be received by your BroadcastReceiver. The only exception is if you use the *AsUser* Intent exchanges APIs to send it.

Also note that an Intent with the action `BOOT_COMPLETED` is sent whenever a new Android user is started. It is only sent to the components of the starting Android user.

**Sources**

Unfortunately, there is few Android online documentation about multi-user systems. Here are the only articles about it (if youd don't find answers there, I suggest you to directly look into the AOSP source code):

- [Building Multiuser-Aware Apps](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multiuser-apps)
- [Supporting Multiple Users](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user)
- [Manage multiple users](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/multiple-users?hl=en)